# SQL Sum Case that includes an is not statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to create a table that will give a count of entries with a given age range. I am trying to sort between AAAAAA, BBBBBB, and other; where other is a count of entries that is neither A nor B within the database. I am looking for a way to write in syntax an "is not" statement. is this possible?

```
SELECT AgeRange
,SUM(CASE WHEN OP ='A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'AAAAAA'
,SUM(CASE WHEN OP ='B' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'BBBBBB'
,Sum(Case WHEN OP <> ('A','B') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'OTHER'
FROM ;ALKSDJF.A;LKSDFJ.A;SLDKFJ (NOLOCK)
```

Comment: use `not in` instead of `<>` here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT AgeRange,
SUM(CASE WHEN OP ='A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'AAAAAA',
SUM(CASE WHEN OP ='B' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'BBBBBB',
SUM(Case WHEN OP NOT IN ('A','B') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'OTHER'
FROM YOUR_TABLE
GROUP BY AgeRange;
```

Not sure what you have in your FROM clause. I also used `NOT IN ('A','B')` as I wasn't sure what R and D were.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Looks like I just forgot a comma in all of this! Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

Logical negation should almost always (can't think of any where it is not) be possible.

- `A=B` negated is `A<>B`, or `NOT (A=B)`
- `A OR B` negated is `NOT (A OR B)` or `NOT A AND NOT B`
- `A IN (B, C, D)` negated is `A NOT IN (B, C, D)`

...and even if `NOT IN` was not an operator `NOT (A IN (B,C,D))` could be used.